# Draggable widget does not change its position

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to achieve the following logic:

1. User clicks on area;
2. A new widget is generated at the specified coordinates;
3. User can drag a new widget to a new position.

Steps 1 and 2 work well, but in step 3, the user can drag the widget, but it does not change his position

That's how it works now:
https://media.giphy.com/media/h4Hhm5vchkcJi3IFqH/giphy.gif

Code:

```
class WidgetPaint extends StatefulWidget {
  WidgetPaint({this.imagefromcam});
  File imagefromcam;

  @override
  _WidgetPaintState createState() => _WidgetPaintState();
}

class _WidgetPaintState extends State<WidgetPaint> {
  GlobalKey _globalKey2 = new GlobalKey();
  Offset locationPoints;
  var commentWidgets = List<Widget>();
  var btn;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    locationPoints = Offset(100.0, 100.0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 800.0,
      height: 500.0,
      child: RepaintBoundary(
          key: _globalKey2,
          child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[

                    GestureDetector(
                      onTapUp: (TapUpDetails detail) {
                        setState(() {
                          RenderBox _object = context.findRenderObject();
                          locationPoints =
                              _object.globalToLocal(detail.globalPosition);

                          print("locpoints: $locationPoints");

                          addButton();
                        });
                      },
                  ] +
                  commentWidgets)),
    );
  }

  Widget dragButton() {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: new Icon(
        Icons.pause,
        color: Colors.blue,
        size: 15.0,
      ),
      shape: new CircleBorder(),
      fillColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }

  void addButton() {
    btn = new Positioned(
        left: locationPoints.dx,
        top: locationPoints.dy,
        child: Draggable(
          child: dragButton(),
          feedback: dragButton(),
          onDraggableCanceled: (Velocity velocity, Offset offset) {
            setState(() {
              print("Location points: $locationPoints");
              locationPoints = offset;
            });
          },
        ));

    setState(() {
      commentWidgets.add(btn);
    });
  }
```

How to change position of draggable widget?

**Update**
If I remove GestureDetector and put a draggable widget directly to stack, everything is ok, but in that case I can't add a new widgets dynamicaly

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 800.0,
      height: 500.0,
      child: RepaintBoundary(
          key: _globalKey2,
          child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned(
                      left: 100.0,
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: Text(locationPoints.dx.toString()),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      left: 100.0,
                      top: 20.0,
                      child: Text(locationPoints.dy.toString()),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                        left: locationPoints.dx,
                        top: locationPoints.dy,
                        child: Draggable(
                          child: dragButton(),
                          feedback: dragButton(),
                          onDraggableCanceled:
                              (Velocity velocity, Offset offset) {
                            setState(() {
                              print("Location points: $locationPoints");
                              RenderBox _object = context.findRenderObject();
                              locationPoints = _object.globalToLocal(offset);
                            });
                          },
                        )),]
```

Comment: I don't see in your code `DragTarget`. Maybe I',m wrong, but I think this is what lacks

Comment: If I understood correctly, `DragTarget` is optional. I can get current position using method `onDraggableCanceled: (Velocity velocity, Offset offset) {
            setState(() {
              print("Location points: $locationPoints");
              locationPoints = offset;
            });`

Comment: As I've said, maybe I'm wrong. I just used it with `DragTarget`. Did you try to use another callback? `onDragEnd` or `onDragCompleted`

Comment: same result. But if I remove `GestureDetector` from Stack it works properly (comment below)

Answer (score -1):

As you already mentioned it by yourself in your update: `GestureRecognizer` consumes the user input (the dragging for instance). For cases like this where you just want to register the user input you can use the `Listener` widget. It has the same callbacks as the `GestureRecognizer` but won't consume it.